# What is the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of a subset in $\mathbb R^2$ in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Let X denote the subset $(-1,1) \times 0$ of $\mathbb R^2$ and let U be the open ball B(0,1) in $\mathbb R^2$ which contains X. Show that there is no $\epsilon > 0$ s.t the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of X in $R^n$ is contained in U.

I'm not sure what the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of X would be in $\mathbb R^n$. I understand that the points of X in $R^n$ will not be in U, but then X does not have any points in $R^n$ since it is a subset of $R^2$ I'm not sure what i'm missing

Comment: Where you have $\Bbb R^n$ you probably should have $\Bbb R^2$; this may be a typo in the original problem. If $\langle X,d\rangle$ is a metric space, $A\subseteq X$, and $\epsilon>0$, the $\epsilon$-nbhd of $A$ is the set of points that are less than $\epsilon$ away from at least one point of $A$: $$\bigcup_{x\in A}B(x,\epsilon)\;,$$ where $B(x,\epsilon)$ is the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centred at $x$.

Comment: Ask yourself what is the $\epsilon$ neighborhood in $\mathbb{R}$ of the interval $(-1,1)$. Does it contain points outside the open ball $B(0,1)$?

Comment: Since U is open and the interval (-1,1) is contained in U, then any point in the interval will have an open set that is contained completely in U ?